# Motorola MT2070 barcode scanner losing connection to computer

Tags: usb, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I have a brand new Motorola MT2070 barcode scanner. Our company has recommended this model widely to our customers of our inventory / point-of-sale software. As usual, I'm configuring one for a client, which consists of only copying an executable and replacing the main menu with a custom one.

While I was browsing the files on the scanner, I accidentally ran the MCL application, which we never even use. It took some time to load, then when it loaded, I went to exit, but wouldn't exit - instead just restarted. On my computer, I had Windows Mobile Device Center (Win7) open, and when I started that app, the computer lost connection to the scanner (plugged directly into the scanner via USB). So I rebooted the scanner and ever since then, I haven't been able to get it to work.

- The scanner's USB mode is on Active Sync
- Restarted my computer
- Unplugged the USB
- Took the battery out of the scanner
- Did both warm and cold resets

Whenever I reboot the scanner, the Windows Mobile Device Center appears and connects to the scanner successfully, and I can browse the scanner. But 5-10 seconds later, it disconnects until I reboot the scanner again.

At the same time, when I connect the scanner, a small window appears on the scanner's screen that says "Connecting" and two buttons Hide and Cancel. I had never seen that window in my life.

Apologies, I'm not at my work with the equipment at this moment. I will edit later.

Added to the problem, the Bluetooth to the cradle is also no longer working either. When I scan anything, it fails to send the barcode data to the host. I've repeatedly scanned the pair barcode on the cradle with no help.

How do I fix this communication problem? I'm assuming that when I opened the MCL application, I must have messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how familiar you are with Motorola devices I'll have to ask if you've done the ***cold boot*** correctly. Sorry...

This device's ***cold boot*** is done by holding down the **"2"** key and the **scanner trigger** for **10** seconds, if less, it'll be a ***warm boot***.

If you've done this correctly and got no good I'd ask if you've scanned the *"Set Default"* barcode that comes in the [***Quick Start Guide***](http://www.juta-soft.hu/pdf/adatgyujto/motorola%20mt2000%20quick%20start.pdf) along with the scanner.

Try scanning it. If needed scan ***"Unpairing"*** barcode before the **"Set Default"***, both under *"Miscellaneous"*. If still no good, try scanning the ***"Cradle Host"*** under *"Radio Communications Host Types"* and ***"ActiveSync Host"*** under *"USB Host"*.

I should've asked this on a comment, but I can't comment yet, so... Have you tryed on a different OS, like WinXP?

If none of this works, call Motorola Solutions (now Zebra Technologies) and ask for a *Clean Boot* image or the shipped O.S. image...

Yet, if no lucky, ship it back for repairing... sorry...